# using dotLottie animations did not reduce APK size

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, apk, lottie

I tried to replace all the JSON lottie files in my Android project to dotLottie file format. In the project a single JSON that was around 200kb was reduced down to 20kb. So replacing around 30 such files should have reduced the APK size, right?

But after building a release APK, I found to my surprise that the APK size did not decrease. In fact, it increased by few KBs.

How can this be?

Comment: APK files are just ZIP files, unzip them and check the content before and after you changed the lottie files.

Comment: I checked sizes of both the apps after installing the APK as well..turned out to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well, APK files are already compressed (zip) and also have [shrinking and obfuscation](https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code), which is what dotlottie format does to lottie JSON. Apart from that, another [manifest overhead](https://dotlottie.io/structure/#dotlottie-structure) is included in the dotlottie file. So it should increase the size of the APK, and that's exactly what happens.